# TiKZ plot x^a* cos(ln(x))

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I wanted to plot the function X^(-1.5)*cos(ln(X))
I can do successfully X^(1.5)*cos(ln(X)), but if I put a negative exponent the code does not work.

I wanted to plot a function that increases close to the wall with the oscillations wavelength increasing as well. Could someone help?
Thanks!

```
\draw[-stealth] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

\draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (5,0);

\draw [scale=0.5,domain=10:0,smooth,variable=\x,blue]    plot (\x, { 0.1*cos(1200* ln(\x))*(\x)^(1.5) });

\draw [scale=0.5,domain=10:0,smooth,variable=\x,black]    plot (\x, {  0.1*\x^(1.5) });

\draw [scale=0.5,domain=10:0,smooth,variable=\x,black]    plot (\x, {  -0.1*\x^(1.5) });
```

[image]

Comment: May I recommend pgfplots for that, and not to extend the domain all the way down to 0?

Comment: Please complete your code, so it is compilable. - starting with `\documentclass ...` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Using algebra to rewrite as cos(ln(x))/x^(1.5) works for me.

Comment: When dealing with unbounded, infinite frequency function plots, maybe Ti*k*Z, pgfplots, LaTeX aren’t the greatest tools. If you don’t mind using high resolution bitmap plot, I’d suggest producing your graph using [GrafEq](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/). See [this gallery](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/gallery/rogue.html) for GrafEq’s capability (in particular the “infinite frequency plot”) and also [this awesome plot](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/gallery/frontispiece.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modify the @marmot code using  cos(ln(x))/x^(1.5) as I suggested above. To make the graph a little more pleasing to the eye, I have a template that I use:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}%declare color here to avoid color clash with tikz
\usepackage{pgfplots}% This uses tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{.1/x^(1.5)}%
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{g}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{0.1*cos(1200*ln(x))/x^1.5}%
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{h}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{-.1/x^(1.5)}%
}
\tikzset{Line Style1/.style={smooth,thick, dashed,samples=400}}
\tikzset{Line Style2/.style={smooth,thick, samples=800}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %grid = both,%grid for major ticks (every integer) and minor ticks
    minor tick num=4,% number of hor/vert lines in a box
    every major grid/.style={Red!30, opacity=1.0},%set the color for major grid
    every minor grid/.style={ForestGreen!30, opacity=1.0},%set the color for minor grid
    height= 1\textwidth,%compress height: eg height=0.5\textwidth
    width = 1\textwidth,%compress width: eg width=0.5\textwidth
    thick,
    black,%Set the color of the main axes and numbers
    scale=1.0,
    axis lines=center,
    domain=0:4
    samples=500,
    line join=bevel,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=2,
    ymin=-4,
    ymax=4,
    %xticklabels=\empty,% remove % at beginning of line to remove x labels
    %yticklabels=\empty,% remove % at beginning of line to remove x labels
    major tick length=0pt,% Increase number adds tick mark and increases distance of numbers from the x/y axis
    minor tick length=0pt,% Increase number adds minor tick marks
    %xtick=\empty,
    %ytick=\empty,
] 
\addplot[Line Style2, color=Peach, domain=.01:2] (\x,{f(\x)}); %color names determined by dvipsnames
\addplot[Line Style2, color=NavyBlue, domain=0.05:2] (\x,{g(\x)});% in the xcolor package
\addplot[Line Style2, color=Peach, domain=0.01:2] (\x,{h(\x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output running in Gummi is shown below: 
[image]

As you approach the y-axis from the right, you'll need to adjust the values of the domains to make the plot pleasing to your eye: the closer you go to 0 the more chaotic the graph becomes. So much so that it will look like a solid blue area, rather than a curve. Set at .05 the graph doesn't look so messy yet.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some pgfplots code producing this plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[domain=0.01:10,no marks,axis lines=middle,smooth,
 xmax=12,xlabel=$\eta$,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty]
  \addplot[color=blue,samples=101]  {0.1*cos(1200*ln(x))*pow(x,1.5)}; %
  \addplot[color=black] { 0.1*pow(x,1.5) };
  \addplot[color=black] {-0.1*pow(x,1.5)};
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to draw this with Ti*k*Z, and I assume @DJP will provide you with a code.

If you want the thing to become larger towards the wall, you could use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[domain=0.01:10,no marks,axis lines=middle,smooth,
 xmax=12,xlabel=$\eta$,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5]
  \addplot[color=blue,samples=101]  {0.1*cos(1200*ln(10-x))*pow(10-x,1.5)}; %
  \addplot[color=black] { 0.1*pow(10-x,1.5) };
  \addplot[color=black] {-0.1*pow(10-x,1.5)};
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The MWE doesn't help, but I think OP wanted x^(-1.5).

Comment: @Teepeemm I reread the question, and added what I think the OP may want. Thanks for informing me!