# Some book to learn to graph 2D and 3D

Tags: graphics, plot, graphs, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I have been drawing in a fairly basic way for a long time or using alternative programs to generate my graphs, but now I would like to learn how to graph in Latex but I don't know where to learn to graph. I've searched the internet but haven't seen anything nice or where I can really learn from. Does anyone know where I can get material to learn to graph? Any complete book? I will appreciate all kinds of help, I am interested in graphics in general 2D, 3D ...

Comment: There are the links on 2D and 3D graphs + Asymptote manual + tutorial + ... in here https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/

Comment: There are many ways to graph in LaTeX: `tikz/pgfplots`, `pstricks`, `asymptote`, and `gnuplot` are just some of the options. I'd recommend tikz and pgplots. Two sources [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) but you'll make things easier on yourself if figure out what look and feel you want and fit the package to your needs. My answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555218/best-practice-for-plots-pgfplots-gnuplot-etc/555274#555274) has several templates to get you started. Some have comments on how to change them (axes versus frame, grid paper,etc).

Comment: For TikZ 2D, start with Section 3 here: https://tug.org/tugboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf. Then read the very clear tutorial of the TikZ manual: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf.

Comment: I also recommend the TikZ manual. And for some inspiration have a look at https://pgfplots.net/ and https://texample.net/tikz/examples/all/

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I will read what you have mentioned to me, I will leave the question open in case there are interested people or other interesting contributions.